# android.support.v4.jar mismatch error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am working on csipsimple where i am using actionbarsherlock library....i added this library to project.....and i have my own android.support.v4.jar .....but i have error in .build() method....i also have error in fragment class n shows the error The hierarchy of the type FavListFragment is inconsistent.....i have been searching all day over internet...n follow their instruction but have no points....the errors still remain....If I try to overwrite latest android.support.v4.jar it shows mismatch jar dependency error....please help me from this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same android.support.v4.jar in your project and dependency libraries you're using.

different version of android.support.v4.jar leads to mismatch error.

Comment: i am using android.support.v4.jar as my library has.....but it shows same error